# Button click count for each list item in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a list and I want to get the button click count for each item separately.
I have created an example [example](http://jsfiddle.net/vimalv86/HB7LU/28388/) but that has increasing all items. Please help. One Important thing, the JSON doesn't have 'count' key.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

var jsonInfo = {"count":["one", "two", "three", "four"]}

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.data =jsonInfo;

  $scope.counter = 0;
  $scope.count = function (inc) {
    $scope.counter += inc;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you can do this by Modifying the array in to object array

```
var jsonInfo = {"count":[{"name":"one",count:0} ,{"name":"two",count:0} ,{"name":"three",count:0} ,{"name":"four",count:0}]}
```

Now modify the html like this

```
 <li ng-repeat="list in data.count">
    <a href="#" ng-click="count(list)">
      <span>{{list.name}}</span>
      <span style="display: block;">Count: {{list.count}}</span>
    </a>
  </li>
```

Then pass the obj as parameter to function and increase the count of that object

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.data =jsonInfo;

    $scope.counter = 0;
    $scope.count = function (inc) {
        inc.count =  inc.count + 1
    };
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/28390/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('MyCtrl', function MyCtrl($scope) {
    var jsonInfo = [
      {
        count: 1,
        name: "one"
      },
      {
        count: 1,
        name: "two"
      },
      {
        count: 1,
        name: "three"
      },
      {
        count: 1,
        name: "four"
      }]
    $scope.data = jsonInfo;
    $scope.counter = 0;
    $scope.count = function (inc) {
      inc.count = inc.count + 1;
    };
  })
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="list in data">
    <a href="#" ng-click="count(list)">
      <span>{{list.name}}</span>
      <span style="display: block;">Count: {{list.count}}</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is the main issue. I can't add 'count' in JSON file. :(

Comment: No you cant. for that you will have to use database